# edit work docucument after phpcopy

Tags: php, ms-word

I am working on a project that builds a client a quality, safety or environmental management system based on core procedures that are required, there are 3 options and therefore 7 different combinations.  I have put together a code that looks at what they need and then inserts data into their client document table, including a copy of the template word document.  The code itself works great and successfully builds the client a list of documentation, and inserts the template document (MS Word).

What I need help with, and I am not sure if this is possible, is to find a way to edit the word documents once they have been copied across.

The templates are located on my `/templates` folder and then copied to `/clientfolder`, the code I am using to query, append and copy is shown below, I am aware this is not perfect and I will be updating it soon, but it does work.

What I need is a code to include within the loop, to edit the document that has just been placed, and insert the company name and company logo, which are held as session variables within my project.  If you look at this sample table here (http://iso-drive.co.uk/public/templates_documents_list.php) , there is a word document you can open and it has the two text areas ---> [companyname] [logo].

So basically I need to edit each word document and insert the two $_Sessopm[companyname] and $_Session[companylogo] within.

```
//Add Template Documentation
//step 1 identify which documentation set is required
$sql = "SELECT * FROM templates_documents WHERE scope = '".$values["msscope"]."'";
$rs = CustomQuery($sql); 
$results = $rs;
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{
//Step 2 correctly name doc reference
if ($row["scope"] == '9001') $docref = $row["9001ref"]; 
elseif ($row["scope"] == '14001') $docref = $row["14001ref"]; 
elseif ($row["scope"] == '18001') $docref = $row["18001ref"]; 
elseif ($row["scope"] == '9001,14001') $docref = $row["914001ref"]; 
elseif ($row["scope"] == '9001,18001') $docref = $row["918001ref"]; 
elseif ($row["scope"] == '14001,18001') $docref = $row["1418001ref"]; 
elseif ($row["scope"] == '9001,14001,18001') $docref = $row["91418001ref"];

//Step 3 Decode Attachment Field
$fileArray = json_decode($row["attachment"],true);

//values from Attachment Array
$name1 = $fileArray["0"]["name"]; 
$usrName1 = $fileArray["0"]["usrName"];
$size1 = $fileArray["0"]["size"];
$type1 = $fileArray["0"]["type"];
$searchStr1 = $fileArray["0"]["searchStr"];

$name2 = $folder.'/'.$docref.'.docx';
$usrName2 = $docref.".docx";
$size2=$size1;
$type2=$type1;
$searchStr2 = $usrName2.",!:sStrEnd";
$attachment2 = '[{"name":"'.$folder.'\/'.$usrName2.'","usrName":"'.$usrName2.'","size":'.$size2.',"type":"'.$type2.'","searchStr":"'.$searchStr2.'"}]';

//Step 4 insert template documentation into main docs table
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO documents_doucments (companyfk, docref, doctype, doctitle, revision, issuedate, status, reasonforchange, attachment) 
values('".$values["companypk"]."', '$docref', '$row[doctype]','$row[templatename]','0.1', now(),1, 'First Draft', '$attachment2')";CustomQuery($sql2);

//step 4 copy and rename attachment into main docs table
if ($fileArray){
$originalfile = $name1; 
$newfile = $name2;
copy($name1, $name2);}

//step 5 insert duplicate records from 3 and 4 above into document history (child) table
//get docpk from master table
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM documents_doucments where companyfk = '".$values["companypk"]."' and docref = '$docref' ";
$rs3 = CustomQuery($sql3); 
$results3 = $rs3;
while ($row = $results3->fetch_assoc())
{
$documentpk = $row["documentpk"];

//insert
$sql4 = "INSERT INTO documents_documenthistory (documentfk, docref, doctype, doctitle, revision, issuedate, status, reasonforchange, attachment) values('$documentpk', '$docref', '$row[doctype]','$row[templatename]','0.1', now(),1,  'First Draft', '$attachment2')";CustomQuery($sql4);


}  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit a Word document from PHP level, you need external library to deal with it, since Word files are binary format and ordinary PHP functions such as `substr()` won't be of much use here.

Take a look at [**PHPWord**](http://phpword.codeplex.com/), which exists especially for the sole purpose of editing Word documents from within PHP.

If on the other hand you want to present the document to the human user, request editing and upload the document back, that's a whole different story. For such purpose you need functions like [`readfile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [file upload mechanisms](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

As a side note, I recommend splitting your code to methods and using consistent indentation, since the code you posted is barely readable.

Comment: Thanks, can PHPWord, edit existing documents?  From what I've read it is for creating new ones on the fly?

Comment: What about `$template = $phpWord->loadTemplate('Template.docx');`? It looks promising.